# not reading the file when it was sent by postman

Tags: request, http-headers, http-post, httprequest, postman

I have a problem with the sending of „Post” by postman

The request is constructed in this way:
[my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqeXt.png)

When I add various headers, I receive always the response „no data”.
When I send the file by the website, on which I tried to send the request, I  receive always the returnable file – sending exacly the same file which I sent by postman.

The Problem is that when I don't send the file from the website, I receive the request „no file” and even as I send the request from postman without the file, I receive the request „no data”

So how can i send the file ?
[request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHv3M.png)

Answer (score 0):

The field containing the file has a name, and it's not "Content-Disposition." Check the web site HTML, see what the name of the field is, and enter it as the name of the File field in Postman. Note that the file field name appears in the request body, not the headers. It will look something like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryzp81ydREocuBHzYN 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile"; filename="0041e2b.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

In this case the field name is "datafile."

Comment: I have tried a lot of combinations with this field name and i still don't uderstand it. i have the request which looks like this in Postman:

https://s22.postimg.org/9n12gsxy9/postman.png

And i have the request from the website on which i based. 
https://s15.postimg.org/gwaloicgb/Bez_tytu_u2.png

Comment: The field is called "file" (not "filename") in your example.

Comment: It still don't works for me. I changed name of this field and i always get response "no data" even if I send request without file. My request looks like this: https://s21.postimg.org/m8flmd86f/notworking.png